# SSAS Get last not empty measure

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am new to SQL Server BI. We want to track fee changes by date.

Our fact table looks like:

```
Date :       Fee
01.01.2000   100
01.05.2000   200
15.08.2004   300
```

Now we want do get the last valid fee for a Date filter.
When I ask show me the fee for year 2002 the SAAS should return 200.

Is it possible to build a Calculated Measure, or what is the best approach for this?

We have over 2 Millions Customers, when i am filled this factbased do i have to transfer 2 Millions fee dates every day? There must be better solution :-)

At the moment i get no Measure when I am filter Date 2002.

thx

Comment: You should consider tagging your question with `mdx` to attract more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Last Ever Non Empty"-approach, as described excellently by Chris Webb in [this article](https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach/).

The approach is basically to create a calculated member that consists of all members up to and including the selected date. From this, you find the last member that has any value.